# Java: Can you call an abstract method in an abstract class?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-methods

if I call monthEndUpdate(); in my BankAccount class, in the setBalance line after it getBalance() gets the balance it adds getMonthlyFeesAndInterest() but in the BankAccount class getMonthlyFeesAndInterest is abstract. So would it do anything? Or would it go to the ChequingAccount class that extends BankAccount and go to it's protected getMonthlyFeesAndInterest method?

```
public abstract class BankAccount{
  public void monthEndUpdate() {
    setBalance(getBalance() + getMonthlyFeesAndInterest());
  }
  protected abstract double getMonthlyFeesAndInterest();
}

public class ChequingAccount extends BankAccount{
protected double getMonthlyFeesAndInterest() {
  if(getBalance() >=0)
  {
    return 0.0;
  } else
  {
    return getBalance() * .20;
  }
}
```

Comment: why don't you try it and see?

Comment: what? scary wombat

Comment: Just curious why you would not try running the code and see what happens, rather than asking?

Comment: because of extra explanation maybe.......some logic.

Answer (score 0):

Since `BankAccount` is abstract, you can't instantiate one directly. Instead you will have to instantiate a `ChequingAccount` instance:

```
ChequingAccount chequingAccount = new ChequingAccount();
```

When you call `chequingAccount.monthEndUpdate()`, the `monthEndUpdate` method declared in `BankAccount` will be called (because you haven't overridden it in your `ChequingAccount` subclass).

That method will then call `getMonthlyFeesAndInterest` from the class that your reference is an instance of (the `ChequingAccount`).

**Edit:** One way of thinking about it is that unless explicitly specified otherwise, methods calls are implicitly preceded by `this.`:

```
public void monthEndUpdate() {
    this.setBalance(this.getBalance() + this.getMonthlyFeesAndInterest());
}
```

In our case, the `this` refers to an object of real type `ChequingAccount`, so that's where the JVM will look first for the implementation of the method. If it can't find the implementation, it starts searching up the inheritance chain to find the first implementation that matches the method signature.

Answer (score -1):

Your Bank account class needs to be abstract; abstract methods are not allowed in concrete classes.

Edit:
In Java an object variable has a declared type and a runtime type. If you look for example at `BankAccount account = new ChequeingAccount()`, the declared type is BankAccount and the runtime type is ChequeingAccount. At run-time the actual method that is called depends on the actual type of the object, which leads to getMonthlyFeesAndInterest() of ChequeingAccount beeing called.

For more detailed information search for Polymorphism or checkout [this link](http://ice-web.cc.gatech.edu/ce21/1/static/JavaReview-RU/OOBasics/ooPoly.html).

Comment: it is just forgot to add it